# Print MS Access Table into pdf using vb6.0

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba

I have saved my output (normally varies every time) as MS Access Table. I need to submit the table content to my client as "pdf" file. Can someone help me print or export MS Access table content into pdf format.

I tried DataReport in VB6.0 and I couldn't save output into pdf. I am getting "Report width is larger than the paper width".

When I manually export MS Access table to pdf, there was no error.

My print DataReport coding is here,

```
With DataReport
    .ExportFormats.Add "OutputReport4", rptFmtText, "OutputReport (*.pdf)", "*.pdf"
    .ExportReport "OutputReport4", , False, True, rptRangeAllPages
    .PrintReport True
End With
```

Can some one help me please...

Comment: If this is VB6 then why the MS Access tags?  In any case you probably either have a report that is too wide or else you forgot to set landscape orientation (DataReport.Orientation property).  There is nothing in the DataReport that is going to break pages horizontally when too wide though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Is there any option to print all column fit in one page....?

Comment: When you manually export table to PDF, are you sure the width of new pdf created is 1 paper width? Make sure your table does not break into several pages, checking all pages or your pdf.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns
Yes, my table break to several pages. I want to fit all columns into single page. How can I do this? Please help

Comment: As @Bob77 said before, you will have to design your report and make sure it fits in 1 page. Change all columns widths to adjuts them to 1 page width and then try again

Comment: If you google "vb6 datareport report width is larger than paper width" you will find all sorts of help.